How is PSNR calculated when the reference file is RGB and the encoded file is YUV?
If I use this command to get PSNR statistics for a file:
ffmpeg -i encoded.mp4 -i reference.nut -lavfi "[0:v]setpts=N[out0];[1:v]setpts=N[out1];[out0][out1]psnr=stats_file=psnr_logfile.txt" -f null -

Where encoded.mp4 was compressed using a yuv444p12le pixel format, but the reference.nut file is a lossless rgb48le format, how does ffmpeg calculate the PSNR? I take it both files have to be converted to a common pixel format, right? Does ffmpeg convert the encoded file to RGB or does it convert the reference file to YUV? Or does it work some other way?
